# Can I map Object type to table using JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jaxb, eclipselink

I used xjc to create a model class which represents a directory. It is annotated for use with jax-b and jpa. Because it models a directory, a directory can contain both documents (files) and other directories so one of the class properties is:

```
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name = "dir", type = Dir.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "document", type = Document.class)
})
protected List<Object> dirOrDocument = new ArrayList<>();
```

You can see that I have a List of Objects which can either be an instance of a Dir or Document class. This works great for marshalling to xml using jax-b but if I want to persist this to a database using JPA, how would i tell JPA to test if Object is instanceof Dir, write to Dir table. If Object is instanceof Document, write to document table?

I have looked at using JPA AttributeConverter, but doesn't look promising as it seems to convert from one type to another, but i need to potentially convert to multiple types.

Perhaps there is another way to represent my model that can be used better for both JAXB and JPA?

I am using eclipselink for both JAXB and JPA implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either make it two separate associations (`subDirectories`, and `documents`), or create an abstract entity (`File` for example) containing the common fields (`name`, `parentDirectory`, etc.), and two subclasses `Directory` and `Document`. Then read the Hibernate manual chapter about inheritance to understand the various ways of mapping inheritance.

Comment: I think I may try out the inheritance method you mentioned. It seems like a natural solution that might fit better with jpa.

Answer (score 1):

Update: I was able to resolve this issue by using inheritance as suggested by JB Nizet. I created an abstract entity class as such:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@XmlTransient
public abstract class CNode {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "nodeId")
@XmlTransient
protected int nodeId;

// getters and setters
}
```

and converted the List to:

```
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name = "dir", type = Dir.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "document", type = Document.class)
})
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE}, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval=true)
protected List<CNode> dirOrDocument = new ArrayList<>();
```

I then made my Dir.class and Document.class extend my CNode.class. Now everything works using jaxb and jpa.